# IPython parallel computing not working

Tags: parallel-processing, ipython

I am trying to get ipython parallel programming working on a Linux machine (Rocks/CentOS 5.4, Python 2.7.2, IPython 0.11). The installation had no problems, however, I am unable to execute any command using `ipcluster`/`ipython`.

Namely, I tried the following commands. On the `ipcluster` side:

```
/share/apps/Python-2.7/bin/ipcluster start --n=4
```

On the `ipython` side:

```
[malkarouri@grid02 ~]$ /share/apps/Python-2.7/bin/ipython
Python 2.7.2 (default, Oct 18 2011, 15:35:37) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 0.11 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: from IPython.parallel import Client

In [2]: rc=Client()

In [3]: dview=rc[:]

In [4]: ar=dview.apply_async(lambda x: x + 3, 7)

In [5]: ar.get()
```

after which the last command never comes back with an answer (effectively hangs).

How can I get `ipython` parallel processing to work?

Answer (score 1):

tried your example on Ubuntu 11.10, python 2.7.2, ipython 0.11 (installed with pip) and it works:

```
In [5]: ar.get()
Out[5]: [10, 10, 10, 10]
```

you might want to try run the ipython test suite for the parallel module and see where it fails:

```
iptest -v IPython.parallel
```

on my machine all 97 tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining a function, not a lambda function.

Answer (score 0):

What does ipcluster said about the config files (profile ) it used ?

Try specifying the profile in the Client() creation

```
Create(profile='myprofile')
```

or

```
Create(profile="default_profile')
```